# check if a property value exists with a json Response body in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is there any way to check if a property value exist in Json.NET?

For example: If the JSON Response Body  looks like this:

```
[
 {
  'name': 'S1',
  'active': true,
  'deviceId': 123,
 },
 {
  'name': 'S2',
  'active': true,
  'deviceId': 123,
 },
 {
  'name': 'S3',
  'active': true,
  'deviceId': 123,
 }
]
```

How can we check is the response body contains 'S1' or not?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=pSIOM5Ofug4SVCLJ68B5 - `var isItThere = Welcome.FromJson(jsonhere).Any(z => z.Name == "S1").`

Comment: Are you deserializing the JSON to some data model, or just parsing it into a `JToken` hierarchy?

Comment: @dbc Im parsing it into JToken hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse your JSON to [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) instance, then check that any child token of [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) type has `S1` value

```cs
var json = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
var exist = json.DescendantsAndSelf()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Any(p => p.Value.Value<string>() == "S1");
```

Comment: @akhildev Does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the json in C#, first you'd deserialize into a real type. In this case that would look something like this:

```
// The type of object inside your array
public class Dto
{
  public string name;
  public bool active;
  public int deviceId;
}

//Then in the controller method receiving this call:
[HttpPost("containss1")]
public string ContainsS1(Dto[] payload)
{
  return payload.Any(dto => dto.name == "S1");
}
```

Of course this is a very basic example, so depending on your use case you'd have more than this. Here however the method `ContainsS1` can be called and would return whether or not your array contains 'S1' somewhere.

Also you'd usually use PascalCase instead of camelCase and tell the serializer to convert between casings. JSON.NET can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check all response body values and do not want to use certan keys

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string initialJSON = "[{'name': 'S1','active': true,'deviceId': 123,},{'name': 'S2','active': true,'deviceId': 123,},{'name': 'S3','active': true,'deviceId': 123,}]";
    List<JObject> deserializedJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(initialJSON);
    Console.WriteLine(deserializedJSON.Any(x => x.PropertyValues().Values().Any(y => y.ToString().Equals("S1"))));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```